# Keeping a socket connection alive between stateless requests in asp.net web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, stateless

I need some help with a concept:

I have a ASP.NET web api .

My clients make web calls to this web service. When the client logs into the service, my web api needs to open a tcp socket to a external server. This server provides access to services. Now web.Api is a stateless application. I cant go the option of connecting on every request.

So I some how need to keep a socket per client open on the web server.

I have no idea where to even start with something like this.

Please could I get your input.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into creating a stateful webservice. Take a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15689/Stateful-Web-Services.

It might be better to put your webservice logic in your socket server though.